# julia 4192*4192 matrix can't be squared,keeps looping more than 7minutes

Tags: julia, matrix-multiplication

I have this matrix which has the size of 4192*4192 ,now I want to have this matrix squared.But no matter I squared it in jupyter notebook or in julia pro,it does not to have an end(over 5 minutes).

Is it possible that matrix mulplication of such size can't be resoleved? In python it will be done in a minute.

[image: Here's my 4192*4192 matrix.]

Comment: Please give more information like the code you used for "square" and the Julia version. In my machine `rand(4192, 4192) ^ 2` takes 1.1 second.

Comment: Your matrix has element type `Any`, so operations will be really slow. How did that happen? How did you initialize it? Can you try to convert to `Float64`, or, preferably, avoid making it `Any` in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix has type `Array{Any, 2}` which means that Julia has no idea what might be inside your matrix cells. More than likely you have initialised an empty array with type `Any` and then filled it up one by one.

### Performance hit of `Any`

To show you what you're missing out on, here's a comparison of creating an array with `Any` types vs `Floats`.

```
using BenchmarkTools

slow_matrix = Array{Any, 2}(undef, 400, 400)

for i in 1:400
    for j in 1:400
        slow_matrix[i, j] = rand()
    end
end


@benchmark slow_matrix * slow_matrix
```

This has a median running time of 3.879s on my machine.
Now, if you array had a Float type you could get this:

```
fast_matrix = rand(400, 400)

@benchmark fast_matrix * fast_matrix
```

This runs in 800 μs (speedup of 4000x) because `fast_matrix` has type `Matrix{Float64}` and Julia will know exactly what each cell holds.

### How to avoid this

If you need an empty array with 0s that's similar to another array, you `zero`:

```
julia> A = rand(4, 4)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.447232   0.951705  0.214183   0.97295
 0.0605242  0.348032  0.882958   0.00489095
 0.320847   0.993347  0.0280731  0.341089
 0.14846    0.448864  0.626297   0.269931

julia> zero(A)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

This will keep the type of the original object.

If you want a completely new array of specific size, initalise it like this:

```
julia> A = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, 2, 2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 2.32289e-314  2.28075e-314
 2.2895e-314   2.28075e-314
```

You can set arbitrary size or dimensions this way, but you must set the cell type, in this case `Float64`.

### Julia is not slow

Just to show that you can indeed multiply such matrices, here are the benchmarks for a 4192x4192 matrix:

```
big_boy = rand(4192, 4192)

@benchmark big_boy * big_boy
```

Median time of 726.261ms.

Comment: If this answers your question, make sure to accept an answer to mark your question as solved. See details here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the type of data in my matrix is any,after converting the type of data in my matrix,the problem get solved!

```
a : Array{any,2}
a = convert(Array{Float64,2}, a)
```

Comment: It's even better if you avoid making it `Any` in the first place.